# jQuery. Google-like autofocus?

Tags: jquery, focus, keypress

I want to set the focus to an input field, when I hit any letter on my keyboard. But …

1) … the field is added dynamically, after DOM is loaded

2) … I don't know how to look only for letters (no numbers, arrows, etc.)

```
$("#table_filter").on("load", function(event){
  alert('TEST');
});
```

Where do I have to tell jQuery look after keypress?
Sorry, I am pretty unfamiliar with jQuery :(

Comment: @JonH: good point, although the OP did change the question (there weren't points when I commented).

Comment: @qwertymk - which means your solution won't work.  I had misread the question at first but you were very quick to downvote me so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @JonH: I downvoted because `.live()` is deprecated and in it's place is `.on()`

Comment: @qwertymk - case in point..you didn't wait while I was editing, you dont have enough rep to see my deleted answer but it reads: `If it is loaded after (dynamically) you need to look at live

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Err live is deprecated now and says to use .on.`

Comment: @suntrop I "un" deleted my post - it should help.  You'll want to review the notes on `.on()` in jQuery to resolve dynamic controls.

Answer (score 1):

If it is loaded after (dynamically) you need to look at `live`

http://api.jquery.com/live/

**Err live is deprecated now and says to use `.on`.**

That will cover point 1 of the DOM.  For part 2 you can use a plug in like jquery numberic: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/ - or build something similiar to this: http://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values.

Comment: @qwertymk: I take it back then and then some

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do exactly what you want. I commented the code as I wrote it so it should be easy to follow.  Keep in mind, some keyboards may return different key input (tho not sure why)

On another post I as trying to help, the guy keeps insisting 19 = Enter, but i have several working programs that say otherwise.  He claims to be using a factory keyboard but, as I mentioned, still not sure of the flaw. As far as I can find, 19 = Pause/Break key (if existent). so you might wanna test with different keys to ensure my "if" statements below are correct.

If it helps, I put a jsfiddle up for ya that should show you the number for each key you push.  Just click on the first input box and then press any key to see its .which code in the second box. -> http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/KCzvh/

```
$(function() {
   // Create new input
   var newInp = $("<input />");
   // Place it wherever
    newInp.appendTo($("body"));
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        // event.which is the "keycode" of each key on keyboard
        // 65 = a, 90 = z, the other letters fall between the 2
        // 90 - 26 = 64! tada, you see all 26 letters from 65 to 90!
        if (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) newInp.focus();

        // if you wanted to focus it for numbers too ...
        // numbers on qwerty side of key board are 48 - 57
        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) newInp.focus();
        // numbers on num lock side tend to be 96 - 105
        if (e.which >= 96 && e.which <= 105) newInp.focus();
    });
});
```